# error when build docker for django and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I tried to build docker. The docker include a django project, the project need to use MySQL. but fail to build when I use commend

```
sudo docker compose up
```

with error message

```
1.979 django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (-2)")
------
DEBU[0000] using default config store "/root/.docker/buildx"
DEBU[0000] serving grpc connection                   
DEBU[0000] stopping session                             span="load buildkit capabilities"
DEBU[0000] serving grpc connection                   
DEBU[0004] stopping session                          
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python /app/manage.py migrate" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

python version: 3.7.16 (required)
django version: 3.2 (required)
ubuntu: 22.04.3
docker version: 24.0.6
docker compose version: v2.21.0

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = get_random_secret_key()
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'project',
]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'articles',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': 'mysql',
        'PORT': '3306',      
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=100),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=100),
}
APPEND_SLASH=False
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings
    command: ["./entrypoint.sh"]
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8000"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - mynetwork  
      
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_DATABASE: articles
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "mysql", "-u", "root", "-p1234567"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 30
    networks:
      - mynetwork  # Use a custom network named 'mynetwork'     
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.16
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE project.settings

RUN apt-get update \
    &&  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tzdata
RUN TZ=UTC \
    && ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
    && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata 
    
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt
COPY initdb /initdb
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev
RUN pip install gunicorn
EXPOSE 8000
RUN python /app/manage.py migrate 
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings
CMD ["gunicorn", "project.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/wait-for-it.sh -t 60 mysql:3306
mysql -h db -u root -p1234567 < /initdb/init.sql
exec gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: You need to run migrations manually (using `docker-compose exec` or as part of your entrypoint script.  During the image build neither the database container nor the Docker network exist, and it's possible to reuse the same image against a different database.